# Discord bot ignores lowercase commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am facing a problem with my Python bot for Discord. If I type, for example, `!Hello`, it isn't working.

I have to type `!hello`.

Here is the Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith("!hello"):
    `print(message.author.name)`
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xFFCF20)
    embed.add_field(name="text", value="text", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="text:", value="text", inline=False)
    await message.author.send(embed=embed)`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if message.content.lower().startswith("!hello"):
```